# Content Script Notification

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Having trouble, and wasnt finding anything else on here that answered what I have :/

Manifest:

```
{
   "name": "Item Sniper",
   "version": "1.0",
   "description": "Sniper",
   "browser_action": {
     "default_icon": "face.png",
     "default_title": "Sniper"
   },
   "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
   },
   "permissions": [
     "tabs",
     "notifications",
     "http://*/*"
   ]
}
```

Background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file: "buy.js"});
  }
  );
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var notify = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
      'face.png',  // icon url - can be relative
      'Hello!',  // notification title
      'Oh hellow!'  // notification body text
    );
});
```

Buy.js [There's more to it, but this is the notification part]:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({msg: "Sup?"}, function(response) { // optional callback -     gets response
    console.log(response.returnMsg);
});
```

I basically want the content script to create a notification, but I didnt know if it was possible while sticking with a js script as background :/

Thanks for any help,
Alex

Comment: `but I didnt know if it was possible while sticking with a js script as background` Why wouldn't it work? Did you test it?

Answer (score 0):

The [background property](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) is only available for manifests using [version 2](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifestVersion.html). If you want to support this you'll need to update your manifest to the following;

```js
{
   "name": "Item Sniper",
   "version": "1.0",
   "description": "Sniper",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "minimum_chrome_version": "18",
   "browser_action": {
     "default_icon": "face.png",
     "default_title": "Sniper"
   },
   "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
   },
   "permissions": [
     "tabs",
     "notifications",
     "http://*/*"
   ]
}
```

Notice that I also set the `minimum_chrome_version` property to 18 as manifest version 2 can only be used when targeting this version of Chrome or newer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to call notify.show(); in your background.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var notify = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
      'face.png',  // icon url - can be relative
      'Hello!',  // notification title
      'Oh hellow!'  // notification body text
    );
    notify.show();
});
```

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/notifications.html#api